# Multiple insert / update in session table of Joomla

Tags: mysql, session, joomla, joomla1.5

I have a Joomla 1.5 based intranet system. User load on this system vary between 100-6k. We have customized this system a lot and using Joomla core functionalities only. I know that Joomla 1.5 is an outdated system and need to upgrade to the newer version or at least 1.5.26. But, we have upgraded PHP and apache and managed the security vulnerabilites. So, upgrading Joomla is not an issue in this question.

We have seen that Joomla is using jos_session table to manage session in the application. Update query is getting executed in jos_session table on each click of every user. Due to this, I can see that multiple insert (for new session) update query (update the timestamp) on jos_session is getting executed.

- Is there any specific reason about why Joomla doing this?
- Is there any better alternative solution to get rid of multiple insert / update on a single table?

Answer (score 1):

Joomla implements its own custom session management (instead of using the one provided by PHP). And it's session management is implemented via a database table.

Each time a user loads your page a session is created or updated (if already exists). This is why you see all the activity on that table.

By default Joomla would use an MyISAM engine for job_session table. This would cause many table crashes for me so I had to change it to InnoDB and that fixed the crashes issue. It may also improve performance, but cannot comment on that.

In the Joomla back end: *Site -> Global Configuration -> System* you can set the Session Handler to 'None' and this will stop using the database and it will default to using PHP sessions. However not everybody recommends you do this. You could do your own tests and see what works better for you.

Of course, make sure you have a backup for your website before starting to make tests with the settings.

Comment: Can you share the information about how PHP will maintain session?

Comment: Sure. PHP by default saves the session data in files on disk. Here is what the documentation says about it: [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.installation.php)

Comment: Thanks. +1 vote for information provided regarding 'None' affect.